# How do download ftp folder on Mac osx through termial?

Tags: mac, ftp

I am trying to download the contents of some [noaa data](ftp://ftp.nodc.noaa.gov/nodc/archive/arc0075/0127422/2.3/) through their ftp link.

How can I download this folder through the terminal on MacOSx without installing random tools? `wget` doesn't exist on the mac. I tried the following:

```
curl "ftp://ftp.nodc.noaa.gov/nodc/archive/arc0075/0127422/2.3"
curl: (78) RETR response: 550
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want , you should be able to install wget on OSX with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). If you don't already have it, I completely understand not wanting to install useless junk, but this is definitely worth installing if you plan on using OSX much. As the website says, it's the "missing package manager" for OSX, and it's really handy if you're used to a Linux-style environment.

On the other hand, it does look like you're getting a 550 error code, which I believe means Permission Denied. So your problem might not be with curl, but with the fact that you aren't sending the required credentials to get the resource you're asking for.

Comment: I ended up installing wget from homebrew... All other solutions just didn't work.

Comment: Glad Homebrew worked for you!